# Firebase: Can I combine a push with a multi-location update?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to create a new object with a generated key and update some other locations, and it should be atomic. Is there some way to do a push with a multi-location update, or do I have to use the old transaction method? This applies for any client platform, but here's an example in JavaScript.

```
var newData = {};
newData['/users/' + uid + '/last_update'] = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
newData['/notes/' + /* NEW KEY ??? */] = {
  user: uid,
  ...
};
ref.update(newData);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to invoke `push` in Firebase's JavaScript SDK.

1. using `push(newObject)`. This will generate a new push id and write the data at the location with that id.
2. using `push()`. This will generate a new push id and return a reference to the location with that id. This is a *pure client-side operation*.

Knowing #2, you can easily get a new push id client-side with:

```
var newKey = ref.push().key(); // on newer versions ref.push().key;
```

You can then use this key in your multi-location update.

Comment: How to use this key? Suppose I have a button that counts clicks on it. Firebase data have a variable (click_count=21). So, if someone clicks button, it gets created new ID because i am using first method. Can i have something like that key, so that whatever i add, it stores it in same key. Even if i refresh webpage.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful reminder that push() is a client-side operation!

Comment: Thanks for the note that it is a client side operation. Dart/Flutter's worked the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this to save some of future readers' time.

Frank van Puffelen 's answer (many many thanks to this guy!) uses `key()`, but it should be `key`.

`key()` throws `TypeError: ref.push(...).key is not a function`.

Also note that `key` gives the last part of a path, so the actual ref that you get it from is irrelevant.

Here is a generic example:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('this/is/irrelevant')

var key1 = ref.push().key // L33TP4THabcabcabcabc
var key2 = ref.push().key // L33TP4THxyzxyzxyzxyz

var updates = {};
updates['path1/'+key1] = 'value1'
updates['path2/'+key2] = 'value2'

ref.update(updates);
```

that would create this:

```
{
  'path1':
  {
    'L33TP4THabcabcabcabc': 'value1'
  },
  'path2':
  {
    'L33TP4THxyzxyzxyzxyz': 'value2'
  }
}
```

I'm new to firebase, please correct me if I'm wrong.